# Crystal Reports incorrectly printing duplicate data

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I am modifying a subreport that prints optional report card comments.  The data that is supplied (via a stored procedure) is in this format (trimmed for brevity):

```
StudentID / Grade / CourseNum / ReportCode / CName     / Comment
9999991   / KG    / EA0_AM1   / M1         / T1Comment / Pam is good!
9999991   / KG    / KP0_PM1   / M1         / T1Comment / Pam is okay!
9999992   / 3     / EA3_AM1   / M1         / T1Comment / Joe is good!
9999993   / 5     / EA5_AM1   / M1         / T1Comment / <null>
```

If a student is not in kindergarten, the only comment I want to print is the one where CourseNum = "EA?_AM1".  If they're in Kindergarten, however, the comments should pull from "EA0_AM1", "EA0_PM1", "KP0_AM1", and "KP0_PM1", and those comments should be concatenated.  The original report would only print the comment from either "EA0_AM1" or "EA0_PM1", but not both (it didn't know about the other two kindergarten classes, and it used a running total to find the maximum value for Comment), but among the four potential classes there are two potential teachers, and this year they *both* want their comments to appear on the report card.  I don't think it matters, but here's the record selection formula:

```
(Select {?Marking Period}
    Case '1' : {ReportCode} = 'M1'
    Case '2' : {ReportCode} in ['M1', 'M2']
    Case '3' : {ReportCode} in ['M1', 'M2', 'M3']) and
(Select {Grade}
    Case 'KG': {CourseNum} in ["EA0_AM1", "EA0_PM1", "KP0_AM1", "KP0_PM1"]
    Default  : {CourseNum} like "EA?_AM1")
```

(`{?MarkingPeriod}` refers to the trimester we're interested in.)

The problem I'm encountering springs from the fact that we want to print T1, T2 and T3 comments separately. I found the start of my solution in an answer given by Abhilash Kumar in a thread here: http://scn.sap.com/thread/3195910. Based on his answer to someone else's question I created a formula *GetAllCommentsT1*:

```
WhilePrintingRecords;  
stringvar array arrT1;  
numbervar iT1;  
if not(({Comment} in arrT1) and ({CName} like "T1*")) then  
(  
    iT1 := iT1 + 1;  
    redim preserve arrT1[iT1];  
    arrT1[iT1] := {Comment};  
);  
arrT1[iT1]
```

*GetAllCommentsT2* and *GetAllCommentsT3* are identical except that all instances of "T1" are replaced with "T2" and "T3" respectively.  I placed these three formulas in the Details section (this section is suppressed: only Group Footer 2a through 2d are enabled).

To display the results, I created three formulas (*DisplayT1Comments*, *DisplayT2Comments*, and *DisplayT3Comments*).  All are similar to this:

```
WhilePrintingRecords;  
stringvar array arrT1;  
join (arrT1, CHR(13) + CHR(13))
```

with "T1" replaced with "T2" or "T3" as appropriate.  *DisplayT1Comments* is placed in Group Footer 2b, *DisplayT2Comments* is placed in Group Footer 2c, and *DisplayT3Comments* is placed in Group Footer 2d.

Using the data mentioned at the beginning of this question, for StudentID: 999991 *DisplayT1Comments* is "Pam is good!\n\nPam is okay!", and that's exactly what prints in Group Footer 2b. Since no T2 or T3 comments have been entered yet (verified directly in the database), I would expect both *DisplayT2Comments* and *DisplayT3Comments* to be null.  However, when I run the subreport the contents all three footers are displaying "Pam is good!\n\nPam is okay!"

Any ideas what I've done wrong?  Or maybe suggestions for a better solution (i.e.: one that works!) to my problem?  Thanks!

Comment: Lengthy explanation but couldn't understand the exact issue. what is the current issue now?

Comment: Are you hoping to concatenate the course # and comments for each student?

Comment: What I want to do is concatenate the comments for the one or two out of four classes a kindergartener might take: because the elementary schools are on a trimester system, the comments for each trimester need to be grouped together and the three groups displayed in separate text boxes.  I have figured out how to select and group the comments together via array variables and if/then logic, but when I try to print out the three arrays for the three trimesters it prints the T1 comments for all three (T2 and T3 should have no data).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was a stupid logic error on my part: the line that read

```
if not(({Comment} in arrT1) and ({CName} like "T1*")) then
```

should have had the not moved inside the first parenthesis, so it negated `({Comment} in arrT1)`, and not the whole thing.  That's what I get for blindly rushing in to modify existing code rather than sit down to think for a moment.  Thanks to those who asked for clarification.